# How can we achive a 403 Permissions Denied for a subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

We have a multisite installed in the root directory (multisite.com) and also a wordpress single installation on a subdomain (help.multisite.com)

In the **root .htaccess** we placed:

```
#START Security: Disallow access to folders
Options All -Indexes
# END Security
```

On the main site (as expected we get)

*"403 Permission Denied.
You do not have permission for this request /wp-content/blogs.dir/83/"*

**Nice**. :)

BUT. We just noticed that when trying to access the subdomains folders we get:

*Internal Server Error. The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.... Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error...*

This is something we do NOT want.

#### So the question is:

**How can we avoid the above result and make the message for the subdomains be *"403 Permission Denied"*** (the same as for the main site and NOT *"500 Internal Server Error"* (as it is now)? We put what, where?

Comment: @EAMann I thought the question fell under the category of *"server configuration for WordPress"* -as per the FAQ- since they are both WordPress installations/databases. Please feel free to edit/moderate it accordingly or even delete this question if you find that ProWebmasters or Server Fault would be more appropriate places to ask. Thank you for helping out.

Comment: Security issues with htaccess are not WordPress specific. The fact that your site just happens to be powered by WP doesn't automatically make this on-topic for us. However, I'll migrate it to Server Fault for you.

Comment: Internal server errors should result in an error log message. What does the error log say?

Comment: @mgorven I just checked and actually could NOT find any error messages in the log files. On the other hand though the .htaccess file itself is modified. !!! Meaning: the **Options All -Indexes** I had added there is now commented out and under it there is **another line** reading: **Options ExecCGI Includes IncludesNOEXEC SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes**. Most likely auto filled by my host (Bluehost). I have NO clue of what that means and more than that I am still in the dark. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my own question

After being puzzled for quite a few many days, someone else (outside these forums) provided the answer. It is quite simple actually. The only action one has to take is to **omit the word: All**

```
#START Security: Disallow access to folders
Options -Indexes
# END Security
```

The best thing is that if (as we did) you place the above in the root directory it "takes care" of all (if any) directories in all subdomain you may have in your server as well. !!!

**For those who want to know:** The reason why the first attempt *(Options All -Indexes)* does not work is because the .htaccess file applies rules to the directory that it's *in*, so you must NOT include that directory again.

The funniest thing is that we've been trying to convince our host to give us an answer to this for the last three days and all they would come up with was *"We are sorry. We DO NOT support this kind of questions"*. They claimed that *"this is a specialized to Wordpress software rule"*, although we kept telling them it has nothing to do with Wordpress itself, but with the configuration of the server.

Anyway... Problem solved. :)